# Kinect 2 Object tracking best method

Tags: java, c, processing, kinect, tracking

What is the best method to track/recognize an object using a Kinect and Java or C programming after having a constant track on the object in 3D space I wanted to have the coordinates.

I know the exact object I wanna tack and wanted to the most convenient way to track the object.

I've currently programming with processing using Java, I'm a newbie to this any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of object do you want to track? Is the tracking life?

Comment: I wanted to track a green circle ball.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's designed for more specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. That being said, I'll try to help in a general sense:

Break your problem down into smaller pieces.

**Step 1:** Can you get Kinect data feeding into your code? Don't worry about doing anything with the data, just display it on the screen for now. Googling something like "Processing Kinect" returns a ton of results, or you could check out [the Processing libraries page](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/).

**Step 2:** After you get that working, then can you identify your target point? Then can you track that point? Again, google is your friend. You might also consider treating this as a separate problem and using something like OpenCV to do image processing on the Kinect feed.

[Open Kinect](http://shiffman.net/p5/kinect/) by Daniel Shiffman is a pretty good starting point, and it contains a bunch of examples that get you closer to your goal.

That should be a reasonable starting point: break your problem down into smaller steps, then use google searches to approach those steps one at a time. If you get stuck on a specific step, come back and ask a specific question (don't forget the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, sorry it's my first question, I just needed a lead. I attempted open Kinect from Daniel shifmen. However, the freenect setup didn't go right due to cmake being an unfamiliar command so I used Kinect 2 for windows library. I have the openCV library for processing, but didn't understand the Enviormental.